# What DLLs do I need for Delphi to run WebView2

Tags: delphi, dll, webview2, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm running WebView2 in my Delphi 11.1 application.

On my dev machine (Win 11), it works normally. It works on test PC1(Win 10), but when I try running it on the other PC (also Win 10) it doesn't load the page.

All PCs have Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime (ver. 99.0.1150.39)

Is there any list of DLLs needed, or can someone provide one.

Comment: The Delphi app needs to be able to load `WebView2Loader.dll` which then loads the rest of the runtime. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667271/webview2loader-dll-vs-webview2-dll

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but WebView2Loader.dll is loaded (I checked with Process Explorer) but page does not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every Windows installation comes pre-loaded with the `WebView2Loader.dll` required for `WebView2 Runtime`. You will need to distribute the file with your application. The `WebView2 Runtime` **must** be included in the main project directory distributed with the source code.

There are two different ways to distribute `WebView2 Runtime` with your application.

1. **Fixed Version** - Package a fixed version of `WebView2Loader.dll` to be distributed with your application. [Download here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section).
2. **Evergreen** - Package the `Evergreen Bootstraper` to automatically update the required binaries, or package the `Evergreen Standalone Installer` to be invoked with the installer/updater for offline use-cases. [Download here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section).

The quickest solution would be to add a fixed version of `WebView2Loader.dll` to the Delphi project directory.

A more [detailed description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#understand-the-webview2-runtime-and-installer-preview) by Microsoft is available for reference to better understand distributing applications with `WebView2 Runtime`.